# Solicitud URLRequest con parametros POST en Swift 5 Xcode 11.5 iOS a servidor PHP

Tags: php, ios, swift, xcode

estoy realizando una petición POST con envío de parámetros utilizando **URLSession.shared.dataTask** a un servidor PHP. He encontrado varios códigos que hacen solicitud pero este es el único con el que he podido recibir los parámetros en el servidor, pero tengo problemas con la estructura del REQUEST cuando lo recibo en el servidor PHP.

Tengo el siguiente código en swift 5, Xcode 11.5

**receiptString** es el nombre del parametro String a enviar por POST con un valor largo codificado:

```
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
```

Lo envío de la siguiente forma

```
        let todosEndpoint: String = "http://192.168.0.59:8888/proyecto/receipt-validation.php"
        guard let todosURL = URL(string: todosEndpoint) else {
            print("===== Error: No se puede crear la URL")
            return
        }
        var request = URLRequest(url: todosURL)
        request.httpMethod = "POST" //Metodo
        let param: [String: Any] = ["parametro": receiptString] //Parametros
        let jsonTodo: Data
        do {
            jsonTodo = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: param, options: [])
            request.httpBody = jsonTodo
        } catch {
            print("===== Error: No se pudo crear el JSON para enviar al servidor")
            return
        }

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
            guard error == nil else {
                print("error calling POST")
                print(error!)
            return
            }
            guard let responseData = data else {
                print("===== Error: No se recibieron datos desde el servidor")
                return
            }

            //Parse the result as JSON, since that's what the API provides
            do {
                guard let receivedTodo = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: responseData, options: []) as? [String: Any] else {
                    print("===== No se pudo obtener JSON de responseData como diccionario")
                    return
                }
                print("=====JSON recibido desde el servidor es: " + receivedTodo.description)

                guard let todoID = receivedTodo["receipt_is_valid"] as? String else {
                    print("===== No se pudo obtener dato receipt_is_valid como String de JSON")
                    return
                }
                print("===== Valor de receipt_is_valid es: \(todoID)")
          
            } catch  {
            print("===== Error al analizar responseData de POST en receivedTodo")
            return
            }
        }
        task.resume()
```

Al imprimir el array del REQUEST cuando lo recibo en el servidor PHP tiene la siguiente estructura. **(El valor lo remplazare por algo mas corto)**

```
[15-Jul-2020 03:41:20 UTC] ===== LLEGAMOS A SERVIDOR, REQUEST RECIBIDO: Array
(
    [{"parametro":"MIIkbgYJKoZIhvcNAQcCoIIkXzCCJFsCAQExCzAJBgUrDgMCGgUAMII"}] => 
)
```

Por lo que cuando intento aplicar un **json_decode($_REQUEST);** me arroja el siguiente Warning PHP sin obtener el dato.

```
$param = json_decode($_REQUEST);
```

**[15-Jul-2020 03:41:20 UTC] PHP Warning:  json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /Users/asdf/Documents/WorkSpacePhp/proyecto/receipt-validation.php on line 17**

Como seria la forma de enviar correctamente el parametro desde swift ?

o

Si esta correctamente enviado como obtengo el valor del parametro si lo recibo con esta estructura en PHP ?

O si conocen alguna otra manera de enviar el parametro por POST que no sea por JSON igual me sirve... intente enviarlo por GET pero no se pudo por que es demasiado largo el dato.

Agradezco su ayuda.

Saludos.

Comment: El valor está en un array, debes extraer el valor del json algo así `$val = $_REQUEST[0];` y luego `json_decode($val);`

Comment: No lo puedo obtener de la forma $_REQUEST[0] ya que el indice 0 no existe. Todo el JSON llega como índice en el array del REQUEST y el valor correspondiente del array es vacío. [{"parametro":"MIIkbgYJUAMII"}] =>  .Es por eso que una de mis preguntas es si estoy enviando correctamente los  parámetros POST en SWIFT5. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar agregando el siguiente header a tu `URLRequest` :

```
request.addValue("application/json; charset=UTF-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
```